# AzureDevops Api call for pull-request doesn't work

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm referring to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), to create a pull request during the build process in Azure DevOps via API call. I'm using authorization as `Bearer` using `$(System.AccessToken)` instead of PAT credentials. In my previous steps, I used `Bearer` with `$(System.AccessToken)` to get the `buildNumber` via API call which worked seamlessly. However, if I use the same in my below task for the `POST` mechanism to create a pull request it doesn't work and gives me 400 error code.

Can anyone suggest to me, how can I make this work?

```
          - task: Bash@3
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                
                
                echo 'Started createing pull-request'
                url="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization name}/{Project name}/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/pullrequests?api-version=6.0"
                echo $url
                ret=$(curl -d '{"sourceRefName": $(BUILD.SOURCEBRANCH), "targetRefName": "refs/heads/devlopment", "title": "test",  "description": "test" }' -X POST -H "Authorization:Bearer $(System.AccessToken)" -H "Content-Type:application/json"  ${url} --write-out "%{http_code}" --output response.json)
                echo $ret
                cat response.json
```

Comment: This issue is fixed, the problem was with my json. json was not properly formatted. after fixing the json all worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was in JSON. Fixed and reformatted JSON all working now. This is the task now looks like with some extra addition:
Title and Description are parameterized.

```
- task: Bash@3
            displayName: Creating Pull request 
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                url="$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/pullrequests?api-version=6.0"
                ret=$(curl -X POST \
                --silent \
                -H "Authorization:Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"  \
                -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
                ${url} \
                --write-out "%{http_code}" \
                --output response.json \
                -d'{
                  "sourceRefName":"$(BUILD.SOURCEBRANCH)",
                  "targetRefName":"refs/heads/<branch-name>",
                  "title":"$(Title)",
                  "description":"$(Description)"
                  }' )
                if [[ $ret -ne 201 ]];
                then
                  message=$(cat response.json | jq '.message' --raw-output)
                  echo "##vso[task.logissue type=error;] ERROR MESSAGE: ${message}"
                  exit 1
                fi
            continueOnError: false
```

Comment: @Kevin Lu-MSFT I have updated the answer with correct JSON and final working task.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You could accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your URL?

In your example:

url="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization name}/{Project name}/_apis/git/**REPOSITORIE**/$(Build.Repository.ID)/pullrequests?api-version=6.0"

should be

url="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization name}/{Project name}/_apis/git/**REPOSITORIES**/$(Build.Repository.ID)/pullrequests?api-version=6.0"

Comment: @shamari it is a typo, I modified my question.

Answer (score 0):

### GIT Pullrequest

I was trying to use your code, yet I had a problem
`MESSAGE: TF401027: You need the Git 'PullRequestContribute' permission to perform this action. Details: identity 'Build\c5f6a8a4-de0a-4081-bff4-928a38d232c4', scope 'repository'.`

The solution comes from
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/tf401027-you-need-the-git-pullrequestcontribute-pe/1441618

`Navigate to Project Settings >> Repositories >> select Security tab >> Type Project Collection Build Service (organizationName) in the search box >> check if the Contribute to pull requests permission is set to Allow.`
You need to search for this '**Project Collection Build Service**' and only then it would appear on your list. There is no `add` button, only '**search**'.
[https://dev.azure.com/{owner}/{project}/_settings/repositories?_a=permissions](https://dev.azure.com/%7Bowner%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_settings/repositories?_a=permissions)

(example) https://dev.azure.com/jmusz/iospoc/_settings/repositories?_a=permissions
[image]

My code was based on yours, an example of a plain curl without an error handling is

```
        - task: Bash@3
          displayName: Creating Pull request 
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              url="$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/pullrequests?api-version=6.0"
              echo $url

              curl -X POST \
              -v \
              -H "Authorization: Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"  \
              -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
              ${url} \
              --write-out "%{http_code}" \
              --output response.json \
              -d'{
                "sourceRefName": "$(BUILD.SOURCEBRANCH)",
                "targetRefName": "refs/heads/dest",
                "title": "Title",
                "description": "Description"
                }' 
              cat response.json
```

As you might guess, when I could not find PullRequestContribute (took me a while), I had a 'Plan B' that was to use a Personal Access Token...
Turns out, there is a difference with Authorization header:

- $(System.AccessToken) - you can use it directly, with `-H "Authorization: Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"`
- while PAT must be extended with a (username:PAT) that is encoded with BASE64, **and** `Basic` **not** **Bearer** so you use `-H "Authorization: Basic ${b64pat}"  \`

The code for PAT is:

```
        - task: Bash@3
          displayName: Creating Pull request 
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              url="$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/pullrequests?api-version=6.0"
              echo $url

              #works
              b64pat=`echo -n 'jmusz:ljfcuww24sa7ywmgvlvuwrn3v7znmuvbnfymfh4xtnt3tbo6bk' | base64`

              #works (empty username)
              b64pat=`echo -n ':ljfcuww24sa7ywmgvlvuwrn3v7znmuvbnfymfh4xtnt3tbo6bk' | base64`
              #not working (missing `:` ) 
              #b64pat=`echo -n 'ljfcuww24sa7ywmgvlvuwrn3v7znmuvbnfymfh4xtnt3tbo6bk' | base64`


              #echo $b64pat

              #-H "Authorization: Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"  \ #require PullRequestContribute 
              #-H "Authorization: Basic ${b64pat}"  \ # user:PAT | base64

              ret=$(curl -X POST \
              -v \
              -H "Authorization: Basic ${b64pat}"  \
              -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
              ${url} \
              --write-out "%{http_code}" \
              --output response.json \
              -d'{
                "sourceRefName": "$(BUILD.SOURCEBRANCH)",
                "targetRefName": "refs/heads/dest",
                "title": "Title",
                "description": "Description"
                }' )
              if [[ $ret -ne 201 ]];
              then
                message=$(cat response.json | jq '.message' --raw-output)
                echo "##vso[task.logissue type=error;] ERROR MESSAGE: ${message}"
                #cat response.json
                exit 1
              fi
```

#### PAT with powershell

```
        - task: PowerShell@2
          displayName: Creating Pull request  - PS
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |

              $url = "https://dev.azure.com/jmusz/iospoc/_apis/git/repositories/iospoc/pullrequests?api-version=6.0"
              
              $sourceBranch = "refs/heads/source"
              $targetBranch = "refs/heads/dest"
              $title = "title"
              $description = "description"
              
              
              $MyPat = 'ljfcuww24sa7ywmgvlvuwrn3v7znmuvbnfymfh4xtnt3tbo6bk'
              $B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes(":$MyPat")) #Note :  !!!!
              $B64Pat
              $header = @{ Authorization = "Basic $B64Pat" }
              
              $body = @{
                  sourceRefName = "$sourceBranch"
                  targetRefName = "$targetBranch"
                  title         = "$title"
                  description   = "$description"
              }
              
              $jsonBody = ConvertTo-Json $body
              try {
                  $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $header -Body $jsonBody -ContentType "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
              }
              catch {
                  Write-Error $_
                  Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
              }
              
              $response
```

### GIT repo clone with Token

I had to pass credentials to repo to a task in pipeline, I decided the best would be to use $(System.AccessToken) (plan B was with PAT).
I faced the same problem as above - `Bearer $(System.AccessToken)` vs `Basic ${b64pat}`
Please note that username is optional when used with PAT (for git clone) while it is **not** optional when used for API interaction

```
  - stage: Lint
    jobs:
      - job: SwiftLint
        steps:

        - bash: |
            b64pat=`echo -n jmusz:ljfcuww24sa7ywmgvlvuwrn3v7znmuvbnfymfh4xtnt3tbo6bk |base64`

            echo 1 not working
            git clone $(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_git/$(Build.Repository.ID) ||true
            #rm -rf libraries ||true

            echo 2 not working
            #not working
            git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic $(System.AccessToken)" clone $(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_git/$(Build.Repository.Name) ||true
            rm -rf iospoc ||true
            
            echo 2.1 working
            #working
            git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Bearer $(System.AccessToken)" clone $(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_git/$(Build.Repository.Name) ||true
            rm -rf iospoc ||true

            echo 3 working
            git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic ${b64pat}" clone $(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_git/$(Build.Repository.Name) ||true
            #git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic $(System.AccessToken)" clone https://dev.azure.com/jmusz/iospoc/_git/libraries/  ||true
            rm -rf libraries ||true
          
            echo 4 not working
            git clone "https://jmusz:$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/jmusz/iospoc/_git/libraries" ||true
            rm -rf libraries ||true

            echo 4.01 not working
            git clone "https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/jmusz/iospoc/_git/libraries" ||true
            rm -rf libraries ||true

            echo 4.1 working
            git clone "https://jmusz:ljfcuww24sa7ywmgvlvuwrn3v7znmuvbnfymfh4xtnt3tbo6bk@dev.azure.com/jmusz/iospoc/_git/libraries" ||true
            rm -rf libraries ||true
            echo 4.2 working
            git clone "https://ljfcuww24sa7ywmgvlvuwrn3v7znmuvbnfymfh4xtnt3tbo6bk@dev.azure.com/jmusz/iospoc/_git/libraries" ||true
            rm -rf libraries ||true
           
            #not working
            echo 5 not working
            git clone https://${b64pat}@dev.azure.com/jmusz/iospoc/_git/libraries ||true  
            rm -rf libraries ||true
          
            #not working
            echo 6 not working
            git clone https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/jmusz/iospoc/_git/libraries ||true  
            rm -rf libraries ||true
           
            #working
            echo 7 working
            git config --global --add http.https://dev.azure.com/jmusz/iospoc/_git/libraries.extraHeader "AUTHORIZATION: Basic ${b64pat}"
            git clone https://dev.azure.com/jmusz/iospoc/_git/libraries/  ||true
            rm -rf libraries ||true

            #not working?
            echo 8 not working
            git config --global --add http.https://dev.azure.com/jmusz/iospoc/_git/libraries.extraHeader "AUTHORIZATION: Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"
            git clone https://dev.azure.com/jmusz/iospoc/_git/libraries/  ||true
            rm -rf libraries ||true
```

Interesting that 2.1 works while 8 does not